# Search by tag on Laravel AND and OR

Tags: mysql, laravel, search, eloquent

I am looking to improve a keyword engine. Here is the context.

3 tables : contents, contents_tags, tags

```
content
id  | content
8 | My content

contents_tags
id  | content_id | tag_id
1 | 8 | 1
2 | 8 | 2
3 | 8 | 3
4 | 8 | 4

tags
id | name
1 | Webs
2 | Web 2.0
3 | Toto
4 | Secret Web
5 | Titi
```

I try to have the following behavior:

So the 8 content that has this tag:
"Webs" + "Web 2.0" + "Toto" + "Secret Web"

It must be displayed when looking for:

- Web(%)
- Webs
- Web 2.0
- Web(%) toto
- Webs toto
- Secret Web
- Secret(%)

But not on research

- Web 3.0

I have to do this in mysql and not in PHP because I use pagination

My current code :

```
    public function searchByTag($q)
{
    $tag = Tag::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')->get();

    if($tag->isEmpty()) {
        if ($q == trim($q) && strpos($q, ' ') !== false) {
          $q = explode(" ", $q);
          $tag = Tag::where('name', 'LIKE', $q[0] . '%')
            ->OrWhere('name', 'LIKE', $q[1] . '%')
            ->get();
        }
    }
    $query = Content::where('status', Content::STATUS_PUBLISHED);

    foreach($tag as $t) {
        $query->whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($t) {
            $query->where('tag_id', $t->id);
        });
    }
    return !$tag->isEmpty()
        ? $query->orderBy('published_at','DESC')
        : null;
}
```

It works for "web+titi" search or "web+2.0", but not for "web" only

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
public function searchByTag($q)
{
    $tag = Tag::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')->get();

    if($tag->isEmpty()) {
        if ($q == trim($q) && strpos($q, ' ') !== false) {
          $q = explode(" ", $q);
          $tag = Tag::where('name', 'LIKE', $q[0] . '%')
            ->OrWhere('name', 'LIKE', $q[1] . '%')
            ->get();
        }
        else
        {
             $tag = Tag::where('name', 'LIKE', $q)
                     ->get();
        }
    }
    $query = Content::where('status', Content::STATUS_PUBLISHED);

    foreach($tag as $t) {
        $query->whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($t) {
            $query->where('tag_id', $t->id);
        });
    }
    return !$tag->isEmpty()
        ? $query->orderBy('published_at','DESC')
        : null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, but it can not change anything. you will never get into the else condition